# Automatic export to .csv when saving .numbers

Tags: macos, numbers, csv

For now my workflow is:

1. opening myfile.csv in numbers
2. applying changes to myfile.numbers
3. saving myfile.numbers
4. export myfile.numbers to myfile.csv (overwrite old)

Rinse - repeat when new changes come in.

So I wondered - is there a way to force numbers to automatically export to .csv when I hit "save"? (i.e. combining steps 3&4?)

(no computer science background, just curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just bypass using myfile.numbers all together. Instead of saving myfile.numbers (step 3), just export myfile.numbers as a csv, and quit Numbers without saving.

This way, your workflow is:

1) Open myfile.csv with Numbers

2) Edit myfile.csv in Numbers

3) Export the current file as myfile.csv, which overwrites myfile.csv with a new version.